# how to delete history autocomplete suggestions from chrome whilst keeping shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to delete chrome search bar suggestions without deleting history

I want to customise autocomplete option that it show only sites i added manualy i used chrome shortcuts to do so.

please help me